# Seaborn - center bins on x-axis category

Tags: python, seaborn, histogram

Given the following example df:

```
Start    Event
February     A
February     A
February     B
February     C
February     C
March        A
March        B
March        B
March        D
March        D
March        C
April        A
April        A
April        A
April        B
April        B
April        B
April        C
April        C
April        D
April        D
April        D
```

When I try to plot a histogram with seaborn with the following:

```
sns.histplot(data=df, x='Start', hue='Event', multiple='dodge', discrete=False)
```

I get the following result:

[image]

But I'd like the bins to be centered on x-axis (just like March is). How can I do that?

If I set 'discrete' as True, it puts all bins together and that's not what I want.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: it looks like that I shouldn't use histogram for that but actually a barplot! it worked well using "sns.catplot"

Answer (score 1):

With `discrete=False` while you do have discrete values, you get a very wrong histogram.

Default, the histogram tries to make maximal use of the space, leaving no gaps between the groups.  You can set e.g. `shrink=0.9` to create a small gap. Note that a bar of zero height will be created for February's missing `D`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

data_str = '''Start    Event
February     A
February     A
February     B
February     C
February     C
March        A
March        B
March        B
March        D
March        D
March        C
April        A
April        A
April        A
April        B
April        B
April        B
April        C
April        C
April        D
April        D
April        D'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_str), delim_whitespace=True)
sns.histplot(data=df, x='Start', hue='Event', multiple='dodge', shrink=0.9)
plt.margins(x=0.02) # less whitespace left and right
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.histplot with gaps]